# Google Cloud fails to deploy Websocket on App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, websocket, socket.io

I want to host a websocket server on google cloud app engine but it fails to deploy. It throws the following error:

```
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build 0ac14646-cf8c-4bd7-9d54-db4c6982d6b1 status: FAILURE
An unexpected error occurred. Refer to build logs: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/0ac14646-cf8c-4bd7-9d54-db4c6982d6b1?project=1043244449841
Full build logs: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/0ac14646-cf8c-4bd7-9d54-db4c6982d6b1?project=1043244449841
```

I understand that websockets are only supported with the flexible environment and I followed this tutorial from the official documentation but it still gives me the same error:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/using-websockets-and-session-affinity?tab=node.js

I clone this repo:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples

I run the example locally without any issues:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/main/appengine/websockets

But I cannot deploy it to app engine.

I can confirm that the project is correctly set up because I successfully deployed other samples from the repo and even did my own app which also worked.

I tried creating a new project, setting up app engine for it, uninstalling gcloud CLI and then installing it again, restarting my laptop and vscode but nothing seems to work.

Is anoyne able to deploy the example from the repo?